# MSER features detection not working in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, mser

Why is that whenever I try to use `detectSURFFeatures(img)` with a binary image in matlab gives me proper points but whenever I use `detectMSERFeatures(img)` with the same binary image  
 gives me error instead of pointing some valid regions?

**ERROR:**

```
Error using detectMSERFeatures
Expected input number 1, I, to be one of these types:

uint8, int16, uint16, single, double
Instead its type was logical.

Error in detectMSERFeatures>parseInputs (line 75)
validateattributes(I,{'uint8', 'int16', 'uint16', ...

Error in detectMSERFeatures (line 64)
[Iu8, params] = parseInputs(I,varargin{:});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
make image 2 double first by using `img=im2double(img);` 
then feed it to MSER
`detectMSERFeatures(img)`

Answer (score 2):

`detectMSERFeatures` does not accept logical inputs, as stated in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/vision/ref/detectmserfeatures.html) and in the error you are receiving. `detectSURFFeatures` does.  I don't know if there's a specific reason why, as I'm not familiar with the limitations of the different algorithms.

You could simply convert your binary image to one of the types listed, and run MSER on it:
`detectMSERFeatures(double(img));`